# Automated Azure Wiki with Power Automate

Tags: azure-devops, power-automate

Can you please tell me how to properly set up my flow so that power automate can add a description from my work item to the wiki page in azure?
This is my flow:
[image]

I am every time have this error:

> "TF400813: The user 'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa' is not
> authorized to access this resource. Azure DevOps ActivityId:
> 5db73cf0-2e2e-4a0f-b671-40f2bc77d439 Details:
> {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF400813: The user
> 'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa' is not authorized to access
> this
> resource.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.UnauthorizedRequestException,
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server","typeKey":"UnauthorizedRequestException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
> clientRequestId: 3d9c4fe3-5492-43bc-aeef-34aa4a219ac0"

Comment: Sorry but you need to provide waaaaaaaaaay more info.  Screenshots help.

Comment: I am update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the same issue in Power Automate. It seems that the Action: **Send an HTTP request to Azure_DevOps** does not correctly identify the authentication information. This issue is from the action itself.

I suggest that you can report the issue to [Power Automate Forum](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/bd-p/MPAForum).

For a workaround, you can change to use the Action: **Http** to send the PATCH request.

Here is an example:

[image]

**Note:** the PAT needs to be translated to based64 format.
**name: PAT -> Based64 encoded**